# Two files with same function name Python

Tags: python, module, duplicates, call

My question is about how computer chooses function to run when there are two same named functions from two modules. One of the modules is imported.

This is an example from Pythonschool.

I have a file called crops.py:

```
from wheat_class import *
from potato_class import *

#test program to select a crop and manage the crop

def display_menu():
    print()
    print("Which crop would you like to create?")
    print()
    print("1. Potato")
    print("2. Wheat")
    print()
    print("Please select an option from the above menu")

def select_option():
    valid_option = False
    while not valid_option:
        try:
            choice = int(input("Option selected: "))
            if choice in (1,2):
                valid_option = True
            else:
                print("Please enter a valid option")
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid option")
    return choice

def create_crop():
    display_menu()
    choice = select_option()
    if choice == 1:
        new_crop = Potato()
    elif choice == 2:
        new_crop = Wheat()
    return new_crop

def main():
    new_crop = create_crop()
    manage_crop(new_crop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

wheat_class and potato_class are children of class called Crop.
Crop class is defined in crop_class.py:

```
class Crop:
    """A generic food crop"""

    #constructor = runs automatically when instantiating
    def __init__(self,growth_rate,light_need,water_need):
        #set the attributes
        #if underscore in front of name, private attributes

        self._growth = 0
        self._days_growing = 0
        self._growth_rate = growth_rate
        self._light_need = light_need
        self._water_need = water_need
        self._status = "Seed"
        self._type = "Generic"

    def needs(self):
        some code

    def report(self):
        some code

    def _update_status(self):
        #code for updating status of crop

    def grow(self,light,water):
        #code increasing growth value

def auto_grow(crop,days):
    some code

def manual_grow(crop):
    some code

def display_menu():
    print("1. Grow manually over 1 day")
    print("2. Grow automatically over 30 days")
    print("3. Report status")
    print("0. Exit test program")
    print()
    print("Please select an option from the above menu")

def get_menu_choice():
    option_valid = False
    while not option_valid:
        try:
            choice = int(input("Option Selected: "))
            if 0 <= choice <= 3:
                option_valid = Tsame furue
            else:
                print("Value entered not valid - please enter a value between 0 and 3")
        except ValueError:
            print("Value entered not valid - please enter a value between 0 and 3")
    return choice

def manage_crop(crop):
    print("This is the crop management program")
    print()
    noexit = True
    while noexit:
        display_menu()
        option = get_menu_choice()
        if option == 1:
            manual_grow(crop)
        elif option == 2:
            auto_grow(crop,30)
        elif option == 3:
            print(crop.report())
            print()
        elif option == 0:
            noexit = False
            print()
```

My question is about the function display_menu().
As seen, the function is present in both crops.py and crop_class.py.
When the main function in crops.py is run, the display_menu() from crops.py is run for 
`new_crop = create_crop()`
while display_menu() from crop_class.py is run for
`manage_crop(new_crop)`.

I was confused because both functions are not attributed to particular class. The display_menu() in crop_class.py is indented in a way such that it is not part of Crop class.
Thus, I am confused on how the computer choose which code to run. A run-down on the rules for this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you `import` a module in Python using `*`, you include access to all classes and methods in the module.

For `manage_crop` and `create_crop`, the `crops.py` file is able to access the methods from `crop_class.py` as it has been imported (indirectly through `wheat_class` and/or `potato_class`).

Hope that helps!

Have a look at the [import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) documentation for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately I'm still confused because if `crops.py` can access `display_menu()` in `crop_class.py`, then how come `create_crop()` uses `display_menu()` in `crop.py`? I'm reading the docs for now.

Comment: `crops.py` can access functions in `crop_class.py` because it was indirectly imported as per the answer. `crop_class.py` does not access `crops.py`. The menu might be *crop* specific, thus why `display_menu` is in the `crop_class.py` file

Comment: Yes, from fiddling around I think running `manage_crop` in `crop_class.py` causes function in that module to be used.